# Why some contract addresses show 0 supply and 0 holders on Etherscan

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, contract-invocation, etherscan, logs

I have a an old list from December 2019 which showed the holders, supply and transfers in last 24h from Etherscan like [here](https://etherscan.io/tokens-nft) . Howvever while I was revisiting the addresses on Etherscan, there were a few address like [this](https://etherscan.io/token/0x6d7db80d12036239b13101c067b46922f6d9359a) which now don't show any holders, supply or transfers. Any idea why this might be so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually smart contract's source code must be validated by Etherscan to let it understand all functions and read it correctly, but the [source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6d7db80d12036239b13101c067b46922f6d9359a#code) for the contract you referred is not verified.

It is very likely that contract does not follow the standard for names and functions, so even if Etherscan can vaguely understand that it represents a ERC-721 token, it can't read all informations.

Also note that token transactions are probably grabbed by Etherscan using events, so if some token does not fire events correctly or does not fire them as standards, there can be issues.

Comment: So is it possible that before the code was verified thats why it was appearing among top tokens but later some changes were made and it is appearing as it is?

Comment: Excluding issues on the Etherscan site - it's a managed site, so you can never know, errors can happens ^^ - no: once you verified code that remains stable _virtually_ forever (in very rare case it changes because of CREATE2 operation, but it's very very very unlikely that this is the case). Maybe it's just an issue with the Etherscan database. You can try by your own: use remix, load a standard ERC-721 contract, point to that address and start querying it. You will see the real data by your self :)